# "All tuners are currently busy" after boot - restarting mythbackend helps

Tags: 16.04, mythbuntu, mythtv

I did a fresh install of Mythbuntu 16.04 and 3 identical USB DVB-T tuners. After a reboot if I try to watch live TV, but I get this message:

> All tuners  are currently busy

In addition to this message, my mythweb has all the headers in place but the Listings page has no content and says:

> Warning at /usr/share/mythtv/mythweb/modules/_shared/tmpl/default/header.php, line 12:
>   !!NoTrans: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /usr/share/mythtv/mythweb/modules/_shared/tmpl/default/header.php:152)!!

After a backend restart everything works.

This is possibly related to tuners not being ready before mythbackend starts up.

I did ask about this in [mythtv support forum](https://forum.mythtv.org/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=1451), but not sure why I get the mythweb problem.  The wiki leaves some questions open.

What would be a good solution for the problem?

Comment: you could delay the start of the mythbackend. perhaps this helps: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1450458#p1450458

Comment: To those VTCing this, Mythbuntu is an official Ubuntu flavor.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at a few ways to go the simplest workaround was to add  "ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 15" line into my /lib/systemd/system/mythtv-backend.service file:

```
[Service]
User=mythtv
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/mythtv/additional.args
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 15
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mythbackend --quiet --syslog local7 $ADDITIONAL_ARGS
StartLimitBurst=10
StartLimitInterval=10m
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=1
```

Thanks to bill6502 at [forum.mythtv.org](https://forum.mythtv.org/)!